# PHPMailer: Send e-mail from form

Tags: html-email, phpmailer

I would like to implement sending email function where I want to allow admin of the system I developed to be able to send email from HTML form to the desired members.

I have searched here and tried all the possible solutions but still could not make it work. I didn't receive the email and SMTPDebug didn't tell me anything. I also have turned off Gmail's less secure apps.

Can someone please point it out for me why it doesn't work?

This is my form:

```
<form name="compose" method="POST" action="sendmail.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <thead>Compose New Message</thead>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="to" size="57">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Subject</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="subject" size="57">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <textarea cols="39" rows="10" id="content"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And this is my sendmail.php :

```
<?php
require 'includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'includes/PHPMailer/class.smtp.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $recipient = $_POST['to'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $body = $_POST['content'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();

    //smtp debugging
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->DebugOutput = 'html';

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');

    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    $mail->Username = "myemail";
    $mail->Password = "mypassword";

    $mail->setFrom('myemail', 'Azie');
    $mail->AddAddress = $recipient;
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to require the smtp class if you're using the autoloader. Post your SMTPDebug output.

Comment: @Synchro removed the class, still didn't get anything from SMTPDebug output.